# Standard floodlight problem

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I recently bought a house built in 1972. It had 4 double spotlight (*standard switch controlled*) at each corner of the house with the romex coming down thru a hole in the wood soffits.

Two of the fixtures didn't work and the bulbs were good.

Using a voltage tester i removed the fixtures and determined neither fixture had power at the wires.

Could the power be piggy backed off one of the working fixtures and has become detached?

Comment: "*Could the power be piggy backed off one of the working fixtures and has become detached?*"  Possibly but we cant see it from here.  It  could be some other problem,  We can **guess**  but it would be best if you could do some more investigation. Have you tested for power at the switch?, tried the breakers?   More info is needed.

Comment: Can you figure out which order the fixtures are wired in?

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yes the switch has power and none of the breakers are tripped. I actually was in the process of replacing the 4 fixtures and incandescent bulbs w leds. guess ill rip the last 2 fixtures off and if that reveals nothing its off to the crawl space  attic. Then Ill also know the order. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you take pictures of the wiring in each fixture before you start disassembling things. That's one of the major questions we get 'round here - "Help, this used to work, I replaced it, and now it doesn't" - because people rewire incorrectly.

Comment: How many wires are connected to the load side of the switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lights could be on the same switch but if the 2 working are in front there may be a second switch for the one in back.

Comment: Actually its one end of the house that's out. front and back. I'm in fla and hate to have to go in attic when its 130 degrees and I have to shimmy to the other end from the attic entry haha.,,,,

Comment: I would be figuring the direction of feed and checking at the fixtures I understand not wanting to be in the attic where the temps can be hazardous to your health. One thing I do is look where the breaker panel is usually the power goes to the switch or closest fixture and daisy chain from there, if on 1 switch the failure will normally be at the last working light in the chain or first non working one with no voltage identified at the non working fixture the problem will be in the hot conductor usually the black wire in a chain at that point.

Comment: Well Ed you were right. We had a switch at the end of our hallway next to the hall light. I never used it and accidentally hit it tonight and saw the spot thru the bedroom drapes. (After I spent 20 min in the attic this afternoon getting insulation glass on my sweaty skin. Thanks all for helping!

Comment: Thanks for the reply Scott I have wired many homes / properties and other than Christmas lights I split the switches to normal zones   Front back , left right similar to what you have. Christmas lights usually in upscale homes are up in the soffits and all combined on 1 circuit. +